# Achievements Google Play Services not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, service, google-play-games, playback

I'm trying to implement Google Achievements into my Android game, but I'm unable to make it works. When I press the "Show Achievement" button it doesn't show anything. No login window, no achievements, no nothing. Just I press and nothing happens.

I'm going to start for the very first. I have a menu with two buttons: "login" and "show achievements".

This two buttons call the methods "LogIn()" and "ShowAchievements()" of this script:

*Using last version of Unity 2018.2.5f1

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

public class AchievementManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static AchievementManager instance;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();

        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        // recommended for debugging:
        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
        // Activate the Google Play Games platform
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    }

    public void Login()
    {
        Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {});
    }

    public void ShowAchievements()
    {
        Social.ShowAchievementsUI();
    }
}
```

I would need to know if the scripts are ok or I'm missing something.

Ok, let's think that this script is correct. Let's go to my Developer Account:

I've done 5 achievements (with icons too).

In linked apps and the google API, I've placed my SHA1 from my unity keystore (that thing of command promt > keytool, etc.). So, my linked app has the correct SHA1.

I have filled all the information.

I have my game in Alpha Test (and yes, with the correct e-mail for the user).
Also, I have in testing allowed the "Testers".

I have published my game services correctly.

I have restarted the process a lot of times. I have payed a plugin from asset store which says "Easy Achievements" (which clearly isn't for me).

I tested with "official" "test scenes".

I have not activated the anti-cheats options from linked apps.

In Window > Google Play > Android Settings, I've correctly added all the information and the "Get resources" from achievements.

Here I let you some screens of my google developer, so if you can see some error or something, I've becoming crazy with this:

[enter link description here](https://gyazo.com/fa71b079db08d813d18c13947223d4f6)

[enter link description here](https://gyazo.com/746732513b4ca0f6c30a6a29767f120f)

[enter link description here](https://gyazo.com/ca332f00770824ba7d6c3f7c76f8c045)

[enter link description here](https://gyazo.com/bba0a7850582be7247b5de08bf7d515a)

[enter link description here](https://gyazo.com/3f6a43e67475816060891ba802d90415)

[enter link description here](https://gyazo.com/d22af172133a8005c1fd7fd459e5b0ec)

[enter link description here](https://gyazo.com/41ce9cb5230ce4f8d89cdb822ab5e9ef)

Comment: You've enabled some debug logging of some sort. Have you inspected that information? How do you know that Login() is being reached, or is successful? Basically, you need to back up and look at your _code_ and ask, line by line, if it is doing what you assert.

Comment: Please upload images directly to your question instead of posting them on a third-party webpage with Adds! Also it would make sense that if it says `Enter link description here` that you enter a link description here...